# Как правильно реализовать хэш таблицу с открытой адресацией?

Tags: c++, хеширование

Цель задания-создать хэш таблицу с элементами класса class Worker. Он содержит возраст работника, его паспорт и имя. Хэш таблица создается по паспорту работника. То есть берется хэш функция и из серии номера паспорта делает ключ. Дальше вопрос, как быть с коллизиями в такой хэш таблице. С одной стороны хочу поместить указатель Worker *head и Worker *next  в сам класс Worker. Но в интернете пишут что так неправильно. Как правильно обработать коллизии?

Comment: Берете следующею свободную ячейку  из таблицы.

Comment: Есть 2 [основных способа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B9) -- цепочки (более универсальный способ) и открытая адресация (в некоторых случаях более экономный способ). Что именно использовать -- зависит от данных и алгоритма их обработки. Опишите вашу задачу более конкретно, тогда можно посоветовать.